# After migration, I cannot see the workflow history associated with the list item

Tags: workflow, migration, tasks, workflow-history

After migrating from SP 2010 to SP 2013,when I select

`list item --> click "Workflows" in ribbon -->select a workflow`

And the workflow history for the item is not visible.

This was available when I was in SP2010.

[image]

Comment: How you migrate from SharePoint 2010 to 2013 using any tool or using content DB approach?

Comment: We used content DB approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a known issue which users have faced earlier.I was able to resolve this issue by running the below PS Script:

```
$url = 'http://SiteURL' #SiteURL where the list/library containing the workflow is created 
$site = new-object microsoft.sharepoint.spsite($url);
Write-Host $site.allwebs.count
$web=$site.OpenWeb();
$spListColl = $web.Lists
foreach($list in $spListColl)
{ 
        if($list.Title -eq "NintexWorkflowHistory") #Replace NintexWorkflowHistory with the name of your workflow history list
        {
                foreach ($listItem in $list.Items)
               {
                       $listItem.SystemUpdate($false)
                       Write-Host "Updating Items Done"
                } 
        }
}
```

Reference: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/bdb63a6d-5672-477d-aae1-2746c66f2d94/workflow-history-not-visible-in-ui-after-migration?forum=sharepointadmin

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/8e2080eb-0f03-4eb6-9d8f-10c3aa89d0bc/after-migration-i-cannot-see-the-workflow-history-associated-with-the-list-item?forum=sharepointadmin